azure-pipelines-tasks-azure-arm-rest deploying version of Openssl vulnerable to CVE-2024-5535
We are using various Azure DevOps tasks, such as AzurePowershell@5 and AzureFileCopy, in our pipelines on a Windows self-hosted agent. These tasks include the azure-pipelines-tasks-azure-arm-rest package. During our security scans using WIZ, it was identified that these tasks contain outdated versions of OpenSSL, which are flagged as security vulnerabilities. Specifically, the issue is related to CVE-2024-5535, which affects OpenSSL versions >= 3.3.0 and < 3.3.2.
We are seeking guidance on how to update the OpenSSL versions used by the azure-pipelines-tasks-azure-arm-rest package or any recommended workarounds to mitigate this issue.
We have attempted the following approaches to address the OpenSSL version vulnerability:

Installing the Latest OpenSSL on the Agent Machine: We installed the latest version of OpenSSL on our agent machine and referenced the path in the pipeline by setting the environment variable.
Replacing the OpenSSL Folder with the Required Version: We tried replacing the OpenSSL folder under this path C:\agent_work_tasks\AzurePowerShell_72a1931b-effb-4d2e-8fd8-f8472a07cb62\5.248.3\node_modules\azure-pipelines-tasks-azure-arm-rest\openssl with the specific version needed to mitigate the vulnerability. This approach is also automated through the pipeline. While this works temporarily, it is not a permanent solution because it doesn't address the root cause within the package itself.

